# Can we send collection of messages in QuickBlox using Android SDK

Tags: quickblox, quickblox-android

We are using QuickBlox Android SDK and are giving the users offline support for sending messages! So, there are situations where user is sending messages when he is offline. And when network comes we will have to send all those unsent messages.

Problem is, now I am able to send those messages one at a time using,

*QBChatService.createMessage(message, QBEntityCallback())*

But certainly, this is not really an optimised way. We need to send all messages at once. 
Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no such possibility of sending bulk messages